# Cast ObjectHandle to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, reflection, activator

How to cast a Remoting.ObjectHandle to UserControl type ?

I would like to dynamically instanciate a UserControl :

```
UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "Client.IndexView");
```

**Error** : *Cannot cast expression of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle' to 'UserControl'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you use the [`Unwrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx) method:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "Client.IndexView");
UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)instance.Unwrap();
```

Comment: Unwrap returns an object.  This answer is missing a cast to UserControl.

Comment: The cast is in the answer :)

Comment: LOL. So it is. I must have been tired. I could have sworn I copied it as-is and got a compile error.

Comment: Also edited a bit for better readability, the line was kind of long to digest.